# Populating DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

My dataGridView does not show data. Please correct my code as I am new to database programming.

```
conn.Open()
daRawMaterials = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from RawMaterials", conn)
daRawMaterials.Fill(dsRawMaterials, "RawMaterials")
dtRawMaterials = dsRawMaterials.Tables("RawMaterials")
dgvCurrentStock.DataSource = dtRawMaterials

conn.Close()
Currentrow = 0

dgvCurrentStock.Columns.Item(0).HeaderCell.Value = dtRawMaterials.Rows(Currentrow).Item(0)
```

Comment: Use the debugger to verify you have contents in your dtRawMaterials table.  Also, make sure you have the DataGridView's AutoGenerateColumns property set to true.

Comment: The Fill method returns a number; specifically, the number of rows retrieved.  Check that value to see that it is not zero.

By the way, why use a DataSet if you're only going to use one DataTable?  Just create the DataTable in the first place.

Also, there's no need to call Open and Close on the connection.  The Fill and Update methods of your data adapter will do that automatically.  You would only open the connection manually if you want to execute multiple commands.